# Angular 2 - send file as a part of form data

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

Does anyone know how to send picture (file) as a part of form data using AuthHttp (angular2-jwt) service in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

you can create object of that file information and send over http request

Like:

```
 var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formName"));
        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            formData.append("file["+i+"]",obj.fileModel[i]);
        }

    formData.append("title",title);
    formData.append("xyz",xyz);
```

And send this formData to http request

Answer (score 0):

Sending a file using authHttp can be done like this:

```
let file = new File([blobData], "filename.png");
const url = 'https://example.com/upload';

let formData:FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);

this.authHttp.put(url, formData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```